# How to export BigQuery table schema as DDL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, ddl, create-table

I need to create BigQuery table with the same schema as in existing one.
In standard MySql there is `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, is there something similar for BigQuery?

Comment: I see two deleted answer which is good. What happened here? The deleted answer is the good one.

Comment: @Stéphane-Fréchette - I see why your first answer was deleted  - but why you deleted your second answer? it looks good one to me

Comment: Thank you for your vigilance. I have undeleted my answer, we are good to go now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing similar to the SHOW CREATE TABLE from MySQL, but it is possible with the use of UDFs to generate the DDL statements of your tables in a dataset...

Use the following script and make sure to replace 'mydataset' with yours. You can even add a WHERE predicate to output only specific table DDL

Copy the output of the desired table and paste it in a new Compose Query Window and give it a new table name!

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakePartitionByExpression(
  column_name STRING, data_type STRING
) AS (
  IF(
    column_name = '_PARTITIONTIME',
    'DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)',
    IF(
      data_type = 'TIMESTAMP',
      CONCAT('DATE(', column_name, ')'),
      column_name
    )
  )
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakePartitionByClause(
  columns ARRAY<STRUCT<column_name STRING, data_type STRING, is_nullable STRING,  is_partitioning_column STRING, clustering_ordinal_position INT64>>
) AS (
  IFNULL(
    CONCAT(
      'PARTITION BY ',
      (SELECT MakePartitionByExpression(column_name, data_type)
       FROM UNNEST(columns) WHERE is_partitioning_column = 'YES'),
      '\n'),
    ''
  )
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakeClusterByClause(
  columns ARRAY<STRUCT<column_name STRING, data_type STRING, is_nullable STRING,  is_partitioning_column STRING, clustering_ordinal_position INT64>>
) AS (
  IFNULL(
    CONCAT(
      'CLUSTER BY ',
      (SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name, ', ' ORDER BY clustering_ordinal_position)
        FROM UNNEST(columns) WHERE clustering_ordinal_position IS NOT NULL),
      '\n'
    ),
    ''
  )
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakeNullable(data_type STRING, is_nullable STRING)
AS (
  IF(not STARTS_WITH(data_type, 'ARRAY<') and is_nullable = 'NO', ' NOT NULL', '')
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakeColumnList(
  columns ARRAY<STRUCT<column_name STRING, data_type STRING, is_nullable STRING,  is_partitioning_column STRING, clustering_ordinal_position INT64>>
) AS (
  IFNULL(
    CONCAT(
      '(\n',
      (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('  ', column_name, ' ', data_type,  MakeNullable(data_type, is_nullable)), ',\n')
       FROM UNNEST(columns)),
      '\n)\n'
    ),
    ''
  )
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakeOptionList(
  options ARRAY<STRUCT<option_name STRING, option_value STRING>>
) AS (
  IFNULL(
    CONCAT(
      'OPTIONS (\n',
      (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('  ', option_name, '=', option_value), ',\n') FROM UNNEST(options)),
      '\n)\n'),
    ''
  )
);

WITH Components AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT('`', table_catalog, '.', table_schema, '.', table_name, '`') AS table_name,
    ARRAY_AGG(
      STRUCT(column_name, data_type, is_nullable, is_partitioning_column, clustering_ordinal_position)
      ORDER BY ordinal_position
    ) AS columns,
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(option_name, option_value))
     FROM mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS AS t2
     WHERE t.table_name = t2.table_name) AS options
  FROM mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
  LEFT JOIN mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  USING (table_catalog, table_schema, table_name)
  WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, t.table_name
)
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ',
    table_name,
    '\n',
    MakeColumnList(columns),
    MakePartitionByClause(columns),
    MakeClusterByClause(columns),
    MakeOptionList(options))
FROM Components
```

For more info check ->  Getting table metadata using INFORMATION_SCHEMA https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

Comment: One little mention, that it also counts "_PARTITIONTIME" column and adds it to create statement, however BQ doesn't allow creating such columns for user

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT
 table_name, ddl
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/spring-forward-bigquery-user-friendly-sql

Comment: Perfect! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I really thought this would show me the `sql` used to create the table, so if I generated a table using a `SELECT` statement that it would just give me that SQL, but I guess I was wrong about that.  A nice pretty DDL statement was waiting for me even though I had generated it from a SELECT statement.

Comment: Way better then the accepted answer.

Comment: Just adding one clarification . The query structure in @Petro Maslov response  is  ===>   SELECT
 table_name, ddl
FROM [PROJECT_ID.]DATASET_ID.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 so in above query    `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa is the [PROJECT_ID.]DATASET_ID .. substitute that with your project and dataset id

Comment: It's not clear what should be replaced (specific to your example) and what is common to every run

Comment: Note that there are instances where the returned DDL can not be run as is, due to line breaks in the middle of long description strings, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  to create BigQuery table with the same schema as in existing one

You can use below "trick" with your new table as destination (trick here is in using `WHERE FALSE` which makes below query free of cost with 0 rows in output while preserving schema)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.existing_table`
WHERE FALSE
```

Or you can use above statement in CTAS (CREATE TABLE AS SELECT) type of DDL